# Mapping one embedding to another using Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word-embeddings, embeddings

I am trying to write a model that has the input vector of one embedding (say $E_1$) and predicts the corresponding vector in the second embedding $E_2$. Both are n-dimensional real dense vectors $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Concretely one is a skipgram word embedding, and the other is a node2vec graph embedding. I have approximately 30 000 training examples that provide a mapping between the two. Since they are both just real vectors, it seems like a trivial task to write a simple MLP that learns the non-linear transformation of one to the other (I actually don't really care about over fitting here, since the domain is closed).

However, I can't seem to get it to work properly.

In Keras, naively something like this should work:

```
in = Input(e1_dim)
hidden = Dense(some_value, activation="tanh")(in)
out = Dense(e2_dim)(hidden)
```

I have tried adding more hidden layers, but I think my problem lies with the fact that the input and output vectors are in the domain (-1,1), and so the choice of initializer, loss function, and activation function is critical.

I have tried setting the initializer to RandomUniform, but still no good results. For loss I have tried MAE en cosine_proximity, but both seem to produce terrible results. In particular cosine_proximity seems to not get above -0.5 which might be a sign. Any thoughts on the choice of architecture and loss function for mapping one embedding onto another (essentially a high-dimensional non-linear regression?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take into account a few factors:

- `some_value` is key here. You should probably choose a value greater than `e1_dim` and `e2_dim`. This may be a problem due to the large memory needs for high embedding dimensionalities.
- if `e2_dim` is bounded to $(-1,+1)$, you may want to set a `tanh` activation in the last layer (i.e. after `Dense(e2_dim)`). With that in place, you may want to replace the activation of the hidden layer with a ReLU, to avoid *squashing the gradients* unnecessarily.
- If your embeddings are directional, or they are in the unit ball, then you should be fine with `cosine_proximity`. Maybe a better option would be to use the [von Mises-Fischer distance](https://openreview.net/forum?id=rJlDnoA5Y7), but I think it's not straightforward. Otherwise, you may try [World-Mover's Distance](http://mkusner.github.io/publications/WMD.pdf).

That being said, a lot of embedded space mapping works out there assume that the embedded spaces are approximately isomorphic and just go ahead with a linear transformation. You may want to have a look at the relevant bilingual embedding mapping literature; you may start with the work by [Artetxe et al., 2016](https://aclweb.org/anthology/D16-1250). I don't know if the mentioned assumption is met to any degree in your scenario (skipgram $\leftrightarrow$ node2vec), but you may assess this with the [VF2 algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f3e1/0bd7521ec6263a58fdaa4369dfe8ad50888c.pdf), like Artetxe et al. did.